Optimize Concatenation of Large Arrays in Azure Logic Apps JavaScript Function
I'm using Azure Logic Apps with a JS action step to aggregate data from multiple HTTP calls. Each HTTP call returns a Data array with potentially up to 500,000 items, and my goal is to concatenate all these arrays into a single large array efficiently.
I’m currently using the following JavaScript code in Logic Apps to handle this:
let existingFamilyTree = workflowContext.actions.Compose.outputs;
const newData = workflowContext.actions.Query_Data_from_third_party.outputs.body.Data;
return existingFamilyTree = existingFamilyTree.concat(newData);


However, this concatenation takes longer with each iteration it takes x10 times to process (e.g. first was 4 seconds, second was 40 seconds), it seems like the JavaScript function is struggling with memory or execution time limits due to the high volume of data.
Is there a better way to do this?

Can you provide an example of an item within the array so I can gauge the size of what you’re doing? But yes, this can be challenging.

Also, what’s the reason for needing to combine them all in a single array? Would be keen to understand the requirement in case there may be a better way.

Here is a pastebin containing a sample item in the array (with much less attributes). The key here is that there will be a BVD ID and a Parent BVD ID which will be within the payload somewhere. I need to use these keys to create a hierarchy and order in which to create records in a system. Some of those references IDs wont be in the same query (the results are paginated) and they are often not in the order of parents first and children last.

I'm beginning to wonder whether it is the JS after all, on a previous run thats taken 37 minutes. When I look through the 3 iterations each iteration only took about a minute (adding up all the items in the iteration actions), but the total time for the loop took 37 minutes? Is there something I'm missing?

500,000 items is A LOT and it won't handle that well at all.  Looping in LogicApps is not efficient.  Your best bet is to use a different approach for this, like Azure SQL or something along those lines.  There are other ways but you'll hit brick walls which ever way you go here.  There is a connector that may help but still, that's a lot of data.

Sorry I think the number is wrong, what I was reading was the formatted payload from Postman, it returns around 500K LINES per request. It's really only around 200kb of data per payload so not a huge amount of data imo. It still doesnt make sense why it takes soo long during the whole loop.

Hmmmm, can't talk to why it took 37 minutes.  Is that behaviour consistent run on run?

I have another run thats still running... 2 hours elapsed so far. Its the exact same query its doing externallly.

I'd actually love to try and help but we'd have to collaborate directly to try a heap of things to see how we could make it performant.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

What's the runtime of the API calls?

There are three iterations, each with a HTTP request. Looking at the history, on average they take about a minute to run. (Lowest being 43s, highest being 1m 13s)

If the problem is with the JavaScript action indeed, you could try using the union function as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78950640/624368

have you tried using union() for old and new arrays to merge and see the runtime?

@10p I have switched to using Compose and Update Variable as suggested. It does appear to work better.

@LavizaFalakNaz Yes, using 10p's suggestion includes using union

I think this is not issue with the javascript, any component in the loop appears to take unpredictably long times.
